# Interação entre páginas

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

Estou com uma dúvida e gostaria de umas dicas para atualizar uma página através de outra página.

Exemplo:

Na página "A" tenho uma lista de produtos e um link para a página "B";
A página "B" será aberta em uma nova aba e tem um formulário para incluir novos produtos.

Queria que ao incluir cada produto (na página "B") a página "A" seja atualizada(recarregada).

Eu poderia criar um script para a página A ser atualizada em um intervalo predefinido, mas isso iria aumentar a carga do servidor.

Encontrei um exemplo semelhante: [Exemplo do Diego Doná](https://diegodonah.wordpress.com/2011/07/08/comunicacao-e-interacao-entre-janelas-com-javascript/), porém a página A passa comandos para a página B. Quero fazer o inverso.

Comment: tem algo nesse link (ingles) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853138/send-a-refresh-request-to-another-page-opened-in-the-browser/16853277#16853277

Comment: @leo-caracciolo: Era exatamente isso que eu precisava, cara! Tentei criar uma variável para a página A para ser tratada na página B, o que se dá pelo window.opener. Obrigado pelo "caminho das índias"!

Comment: @LipESprY Coloque a resposta nessa sua pergunta mesmo e marque como a ideal, ao invés de colocar a resposta na pergunta e mudar o título.

Comment: Bom teres encontrado uma solução. Dá uma olhada também em na coluna "relacionado", no lado direito, pois já há aqui algumas perguntas sobre isso.

Comment: @Thiago Lunardi: Feito! @Sergio: Eu li os tópicos relacionados e nenhum satisfez minha necessidade. Realmente, o que resolveu foi o `window.opener`. O que dificultou a pesquisa foi o termo para a busca. Mas de qualquer forma, obrigado pelo apoio! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**SOLUÇÃO:** Seguindo o "Caminho das índias" indicado pelo @leo-caracciolo:
[@lexmihaylov: Send a refresh request to another page opened in the browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16853138/send-a-refresh-request-to-another-page-opened-in-the-browser/16853277#16853277), consegui resolver manipulando a página A (mãe) através do `window.opener`.

Então, o recarregamento(refresh) se daria pelo comando `window.opener.location.reload()` que é lançado pela página B.